# Calling JavaScript from DevEx UploadController code behind not responding

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, devexpress

Please read everything before responding so you can understand fully

---

I'm currently calling a JavaScript function after files have been uploaded using a DevExpress UploadController.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSuccess() {
     lblUploadFiles_Details.SetVisible(true); //set the success label visibility to true
    }
</script>
```

I am currently calling the single function using the built in `ClientSideEvents` setting.

```
<dx:ASPxUploadControl runat="server" ID="uploadControlFiles_Details" NullText="Select Files..." Width="300px" Visible="false" Theme="BlackGlass" ShowProgressPanel="true" UploadMode="Standard" ShowUploadButton="true" OnFileUploadComplete="uploadControlFiles_Details_FileUploadComplete" FileUploadMode="OnPageLoad">
    <AdvancedModeSettings EnableMultiSelect="true" EnableFileList="true" EnableDragAndDrop="true"></AdvancedModeSettings>
    <ClientSideEvents FileUploadComplete="showSuccess" />
```

Very simple, this setup works great for a single function call.

---

**However**, I now require the ability to call two functions based on whether a file exists or not. I need to showSuccess() when the file exists and saves, and make another called showFailure() to show when the file already exists. I can achieve this part easily, no problems there. However, **it seems that my JavaScript is not being fired from the UploadController's code behind**.

The code resides in the UploadController's `FileUploadComplete` function. This is my current attempt, I have tried many iterations of this style of call:

```
bool exists = File.Exists(resultFileUrl);
if (exists == false)
{ //if file does not exist, show success
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showsuccessmessage", "<script>showSuccess();</script>");
    //saving occurs after
}
else
{ //if file exists, show fail
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showfailmessage", "<script>showFail();</script>");
    //do not save
}
```

Code hits it, but the JavaScript does not fire, everything else carries on correctly. Any ideas? **I have had issues with the DevEx UploadController not responding to code in it's code behind before**. For example, if I try to manually set a `label.visible = true` it will not respond to that. This is the reason I am using JavaScript to show the label instead.